# Python ImportError (Cannot import name Variables)

Tags: python

I have done some research on this question and nothing seems to fix it, I suspect I may be accidentally circularly importing somewhere, but this one has stumped me.

This package is a Python IRC Service framework. The issue occurs when dynamically loading a module (via `imp.load_source()`), and the new module tries to import something from the src folder (Variables.py). It fails with "Cannot import name Variables", yet, it imports another module from the same directory without complaint.

Here is the specific error:

> **ERROR: ModLoad(): Unable to load module
>   /home/sam/workspace/Affinity/bin/../modules/ircd_affinity.py:
>   cannot import name Variables
>   **

This is the full file for modules/ircd_affinity.py: [ircd_affinity.py](https://github.com/miniCruzer/Affinity/raw/master/modules/ircd_affinity.py), and src/Variables.py: [Variables.py](https://github.com/miniCruzer/Affinity/blob/master/src/Variables.py)

If it helps. browse the entire repository... this (https://github.com/miniCruzer/Affinity/blob/master/src/Affinity.py) module (starting at line **123**) loads modules.

I would appreciate if all responses were kept relevant to the specific issue at hand. Yes, it may be tempting to suggest other things I'm doing wrong or otherwise throughout the entire package - I am welcome to suggestions: please e-mail them to me.

Comment: Just as a debugging tactic, have you tried renaming src to something more unique and try importing with the new name?  Maybe it's possible that it's looking at a different "src" module. "Client" is also common.

Comment: Just tried that, I renamed 'src' to 'herp', it gives me the same error, so it is indeed looking at the proper directory.

Comment: Ok.  The other possibility is that there is some error happening during the import of the Variables module.  If you removed everything from the "Variables.py" file, will it import correctly?  If so, then it's just a matter of re-adding little bits at a time to see what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Show the full traceback. Look through it for *evidence* of (attempted) circular import.

Run Python with the `-v` option ... what does that tell you?

Look at the contents of `sys.path` and `sys.modules` just before the error happens.

"**ERROR: ModLoad(): Unable to ..." doesn't look line a Python-raised error. Is that in your code? If so, dig deeper; why is it raised?